# Can I run OpenGL 3.3 or higher (with or without HW acceleration) on 12.10 with Intel graphics?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, intel-graphics, opengl

I'm currently taking a graphics programming class. All the assignments have to be done using OpenGL 3.3 (shader based).

When I try to compile my code on my laptop (sony Vaio running 12.10), I get the 
error

```
error: undefined reference to 'glDrawArrays'.
```

The trick here is I don't care if it's fast. I realize the driver support might not be there, but I'm just looking for some way to get my code to actually compile and run. Is there an intel driver that supports this? Is there a software-based openGL that I could use instead?

I've got a hybrid intel/ATI graphics card, but any time I try to install flgrx I either get a desktop with no dash or I get no Xserver at all.

Here's a few snippets from my glxinfo output: (the whole thing is too long to put here)

```
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4 
...
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile 
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 9.0
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
```

And here's some stuff from my lspci:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Whistler [AMD Radeon HD 6600M Series]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel Graphics doesn't support OpenGL 3.3 yet. They [are still working](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTMwMDg) towards getting GL 3.1 ready in Mesa 9.1.

Also I am sorry that I am unaware of any methods to use Software rendering for the same.

Given that, your best bet would be to use your inbuilt AMD card with Catalyst 13.1 as AMD already supports upto OpenGL 4.2. I am specifically recommending Catalyst 13.1 because it supports Xorg 1.13 properly, (which was not the case in the previous driver releases) , which means you will no longer have trouble logging in your Ubuntu 12.10 desktop.

Here is [the download link](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx) for the same

To install, either you can directly run the installer file, which works just fine, [but this is a better way to install Catalyst driver by generating .deb files](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29) , so that you would not have any trouble removing the drivers if you wish to.

Lastly, I am doubtful if you can get hybrid graphics working in Catalyst 13.1 , which mostly seems hit and miss and highly unpredictable in the binary blob, in that case your safest bet is to use Catalyst 12.10 but then you will have to downgrade your Xorg version to 1.12.

Comment: That is very useful! Do you know how to force a downgrade to Xorg 1.12?

Comment: you can use this guide here to do the job http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12346846